# Java 11 environment specific profiling in AWS lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written AWS lambda using java 11 runtime, not the lambda snippet require to invoke external API, the APIs are different for dev, qa, uat and preprod environment.

There is no framework has been integrating, the pure Java SDK is used to write the lambda handler.

I have created environment specific properties file, dev.properties, qa.properties etc.
I tried to create the jar using maven profile like below

I have added profile section in my pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id></id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env></env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <env>-local</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <env>-dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <env>-qa</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>preprod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>-preprod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>-prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <finalName>trv-lambda</finalName>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/application${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

And then after, I used the below command

```
mvn -P dev clean install
```

but it didn't work.

Then I tried to specify the environment variables inside AWS Lambda, but later I realized that it won't work, because I have trigger for every env, but I have single lambda to trigger for all the environment, how do I identify which profile need to pick, for single time, only single jar can be created, so I am stuck here

I want to figure out the way to achieve the profiling just like we used to did in Spring boot.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, you shouldn't have a single Lambda function for multiple (dev/prod/etc) environments.

Comment: I have single lambda function , right, now that lambda is purely written using java APIs no framework, right, now I have multiple env like qa,dev,statging, right. I am not able to achieve the environment specific profiling, what is the approach, using ultiple lambda for each env??\

Comment: I'm saying that if you have 3 environments (qa, dev, staging) then you should have 3 Lambda functions. Their code might be identical but they are 3 different Lambda functions and hence each can have its own environment variables or XML settings file or whatever so they can each do environment-specific things. Ideally, they'd also be deployed in 3 different AWS accounts, but that's for another day.

Comment: Fair enough, that means we don't have any provision to achieve env profiling just like spring boot in aws lambda java, please correct my understanding.

Comment: I'd expect you to be able to dictate which profile is active through a Lambda environment variable (see [example](https://www.kapresoft.com/java/2019/10/20/aws-lambda-spring-boot-profiles.html)). Each of your 3 Lambda functions would have a different value set for the active profile.

Comment: Your maven script already builds 3 different packages depending on the profile selected at build time.  Unless the caller to your Lambda specifies the environment how would the code "know" that which environment is being used?

Comment: That "How would...' I want to figured it out, if maven already build the selected profile, then How I tell lambda that you need to pick this profile, please help me on this